# unable to show custom error message in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm writing a register user function in ( using Flask, Python, Jinja2) which i'm checking if a username (or email) is already present and if so shows an error to below TextField.

register code is:

```
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = SignupForm()
    error = None
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      user_by_name = Users.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
      user_by_email = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
      if user_by_name:
        error = 'Username already taken. Choose another'
        return render_template('register.html', form=form, error = error)
      elif user_by_email:
        error = 'Email already registered. Login or register with another Email'
        return render_template('register.html', form=form, error = error)
      else:
         #Add user details to DB logic
          return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form, error = error)
```

I have a **macro** defined in a file `util.html`

```
    {% macro render_field(field) %}
    <div class="control-group {% if field.errors %}error{% endif %}">
        {% if kwargs.get('label', True) %}
            {{ field.label(class="control-label") }}
        {% endif %}
        <div class="controls">
            {{ field(**kwargs) }}
            {% for error in field.errors %}
                <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
   {% endmacro %}
```

and using this **macro** in `register.html` as:

```
{% from "util.html" import render_field %}

{% extends "base.html" %} 

{% block content %}
    <form method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ render_field(form.username, label=True, class="input-xlarge", autofocus="autofocus", errors=error) }}
        {{ render_field(form.password, label=True, class="input-xlarge", autofocus="autofocus") }}
        {{ render_field(form.confirm, label=True, class="input-xlarge", autofocus="autofocus") }}
        {{ render_field(form.email, label=True, class="input-xlarge", autofocus="autofocus", errors=error) }}        

        <button class="btn" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Now when i test the `localhost:5000/register` with duplicate *username* or *email* address it doesn't show any error at all (also doesn't add any user into DB which is okay).
But when i enter any *wrong email* or *leave any field blank* it shows respective `error`, but not showing the `error` which i want to pass using `register` view.

Is there any Jinja2 related logic missing?

And why its showing `errors` related to blank field or wrong `email` but not which i try to pass on duplicate `username` etc.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you doing it wrong :)

```
{% for error in field.errors %}
      <p class="help-block">{{ error }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

This macro searches for error in respective field.errors

But you pass error context variable, which is not attached to the field.

The right way to solve this will be to add `def validate_user` to your form definition and check for everything in there.
If it goes wrong -> raise ValidationError(message)
See example here:
[WTForms documentation](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#custom-validators)

With this approach, your validate_on_submit() should not return True if it is not validated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just flash the error like this
sample code
file: views.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # some checks which provided error        
    if error:
        flash(error)
    return render_template('template.html')
```

file template.html

```
{% for category, msg in get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true) %}
    <div class="category">{{ msg|safe }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```