# wtform EqualTo does't validate

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm trying to validate a form using EqualTo validator but even if I test with different inputs the form does't throw any error.

this is the code of route:

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    form = Form()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        pass

    
    return render_template("register.html", form=form)
```

this is the code of form class:

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    user_name = StringField(label="Username", validators=[
                            DataRequired(), Length(min=4, max=25)])
    email = StringField(label="Email id", validators=[DataRequired()])
    password = PasswordField(label="Password", validators=[
                             DataRequired()])
    retype_password = PasswordField(
        label="Retype Password", validators=[EqualTo('password', "not equal"), DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField(label="Creat account", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
retype_password = PasswordField('Retype Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
```

`Retype Password` is the label name for your input field.

Please make sure that you are writing proper error messages in you register.html page.

[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852927/unable-to-show-custom-error-message-in-jinja2-template)!

Comment: tried still not working.

Comment: add EqualTo('retype_password') to password field validators list, and remove it from retype_password

Comment: Have you include <code>EqualTo</code> in the <code>from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, Email, EqualTo</code>. After this it might work